# I have to write a Java program that displays how many lines would pass through the origin (0,0)

Tags: java

```
   public class StraightLines 
{
    public static int max=10;
    public static int count=10;

    public static int gcf(int x, int y) //my method
    {
        while (x != 0 && y != 0)
        {
            if (x >= y)
            {
                x = x - y;
            }
            else
                y = y - x;
        }
        if (x == 0) return y;
        else return x;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) //If two lines have the same 
    {                                      // slope then don't count them
        for(int x=0; x<=max ; x++)           
        {
            for(int y=0; y<=max; y++ )
            {
                if(1<=y && y<=x && x<=100)
                {
                    if(gcf(x,y)==1)
                    {
                        count ++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(count+ " straight lines would pass through the origin (0, 0).");
    }
}
```

// This is my program so far, but if there are two lines with the same slope it has to display only one of those lines and I'm unsure how to do that. If someone could help me that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: So you need to specify the first `x` and `y` pair which results in an intersection of the origin?

Comment: Yes. The exact question in the book is: How many different lines pass through the origin (0,0) and a point with coordinates (x,y) such that 1<=y<=x<=100 ? Write a program to find out. I'm pretty sure my program at the moment is displaying all of the lines that are passing through, so if three lines with the same slope pass through the origin I am only supposed to display one.

Comment: You'll need a variable to store the coordinate. You could use the `Point` type to wrap the coordinates in a single object. Where you declare your variables, you should have a `Point intersection;`. Instead of `count++`, you should do `intersection = new Point(x, y);`. This will store a point. However, you should also end/exit the loops as soon as you find a valid coordinate (avoids wasting time). You only need 1 coordinate, so once it's found, there's no more need for looping. How? That's a different Q. You could then access the coordinates via `intersection.getX()` and `intersection.getY()`.

Comment: Would it be more efficient if I did this in a whole other method?

Comment: Nope, would be a huge waste of time. Your logic already tracks when a valid coordinate is found. The only issue is, you increase a counter, opposed to actually storing the coordinate somewhere (to be used later for printing, or whatever else you may need it for). All you have to do is switch from increasing a counter to storing the first valid coordinate. Technically, it doesn't have to be the *first* valid coordinate, so exiting the loops isn't a requirement. It simply avoids looking for extra valid coordinates. All you have to do is replace the counter with a way to store the coordinate.

Comment: Okay I understand what you are talking about, can you give me an example of this? Because I have never worked with point type.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a `Point` object. You can simply declare `int validX, validY;` and initialize those.